# Atomically searchKeys() and put() in a ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I am developing a web server in java which, among other things, is supposed to implement a challenge service between couples of users.
Each user can compete in only one challenge at a time.
Actually I am storing the "Challenge" objects in a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Challenge>` and I am using a `String` that is the union of the two players usernames as keys for mappings.
For example, if the usernames of the two players are "Mickey" and "Goofy" then the key of the `Challenge` object inside the `ConcurrentHashMap` will be the string:

`Mickey:Goofy`

When recording a new challenge between two users in the `ConcurrentHashMap`, i have to check if they are already engaged in others challenges before actually putting the challenge in the Map, in other words, i have to check if there is a key stored in the Map that contains one of the two usernames of the players which want to start the new challenge.

For example, given a filled `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Challenge>` and a challenge request for the users `Mickey` and `Goofy`, i want to know in an atomic way and without locking whole map, if one (or eventually both) of them is/are already engaged in other registered challenge within the Map and if not, then put the new Challenge in the Map.
I hope to have been clear enough.

Do any of you have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to atomically do: 1. find key `Mickey:Goovy` 2. If not found find key starting with `Mickey:` 3. If not found find key starting with `Goofy:` 4. If not found find key ending with `:Mickey` 5. if not found find key ending with `:Goofy` 6. If not found add key `Mickey:Goofy`. Is that right?

Comment: Are you able to reconsider the design? I'd say that having two maps, one for mapping a *single* user to a challenge and the second for mapping a challenge to a group of users, would be a better approach.

Comment: If a player can be engaged in only challange at a time, why not move the player names to `Challenge` directly and then `put` each player name with that challenge in the `ConcurrentHashMap`. Then you can write a (synchonized) method `isEngaged(String, String)` and atomically check if two players are engaged. That allows you to at least read from the map while adding new challenges.

Comment: @ernest_k Yes, that is the behavior i am looking for.

Comment: @Glains What about atomicity of insertions and removals in that structure?

Comment: @AlessandroMeschi Writes must be synchonized, but at least the lookups are fast.

Comment: I hope, you make sure that no user name can contain a colon. Using string concatenation for compound keys is both, inefficient and error prone.

Answer (score 6):

Using string concatenation is a bad choice for a compound key. String concatenation is an expensive operation and it doesn’t guaranty uniqueness, as the key becomes ambiguous when one of the strings contains the separator of your choice.

Of course, you can forbid that particular character in user names, but this adds additional requirements you have to check, whereas a dedicated key object holding two references is simpler and more efficient. You may even use a two element `List<String>` as an add-hoc key type, as it has useful `hashCode` and `equals` implementations.

But since you want to perform lookups for both parts of the compound key anyway, you should not use a compound key in the first place. Just associate both user names with the same `Challenge` object. This still can’t be done in a single atomic operation, but it doesn’t need to:

```
final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Challenge> challenges = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

Challenge startNewChallenge(String user1, String user2) {
    if(user1.equals(user2))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("same user");

    Challenge c = new Challenge();

    if(challenges.putIfAbsent(user1, c) != null)
        throw new IllegalStateException(user1+" has an ongoing challenge");

    if(challenges.putIfAbsent(user2, c) != null) {
        challenges.remove(user1, c);
        throw new IllegalStateException(user2+" has an ongoing challenge");
    }

    return c;
}
```

This code will never overwrite an existing value. If both `putIfAbsent` were successful, both user definitely had no ongoing challenge and are now both associated with the same new challenge.

When the first `putIfAbsent` succeeded but the second fails, we have to remove the first association. `remove(user1, c)` will only remove it when the user still is associated with our new challenge. When all operations on the map follow the principle to never overwrite an existing entry (unless all prerequisites are met), this is not necessary, a plain `remove(user1)` would do as well. But it doesn’t hurt to use the safe variant here.

The only issue with the non-atomicity is that two overlapping attempts involving the same user could both fail, due to the temporarily added first user, when actually one of them could succeed. I do not consider that a significant problem; the user simply shouldn’t attempt to join two challenges at the same time.

Comment: I had (mentally) thought of the same kind of solution and implementation. Agreed about the limitation too. I would have just added another corner case : if user1 is already in a challenge with user2, maybe this would not be an exceptional case, just a normal return. But it has not been specified in the original question.

Comment: @GPI yes, I’d clearly separate “register new challenge” and “get existing challenge” operations, as the later bears the potential of race conditions in the subsequent use. It works best, if `startNewChallenge` is invoked by code responsible for the entire life cycle management of a particular `Challenge`, until the final removal, whereas all other queries are only for status messages, which can cope with the fact that they may be outdated as soon as the query method returns.

Comment: @Holger Yes, I structured the logic of the challenge system according to what you said, so "register new challenge” and “get existing challenge” are two separated operations, but the code which invokes `startNewChallenge` can not manage the entire lifecycle of the `Challenge`. The `Challenge` status changing and subsequent removal operations are executed eventually by different threads and likely in different and unpredictable moments.
For this reasons I think that removal should be done in the same order as the insertion. Am i wrong?

Comment: The important point is, what happens if a thread queries a key for a challenge and processes the challenge while another thread removes it from the map. If this kind of concurrency imposes a problem, you need an additional mechanism to lock or invalidate a particular challenge object. Besides that, removal itself is not a big problem 1) check that both users are associated with the same challenge object 2) use the `remove(key, expectedValue)` method shown in the answer to safely remove both keys only if still mapped to the already checked challenge.

Comment: @GPI I would really appreciate if you could help me understand how the following scenario would happen: "The only issue with the non-atomicity is that two overlapping attempts involving the same user could both fail, due to the temporarily added first user, when actually one of them could succeed.". Thank you.

Comment: @Tarun just imagine two concurrent attempts for `startNewChallenge("foo", "bar")` and `startNewChallenge("bar", "foo")` on an initially empty map. In principle, it would be possible to accept one and only reject the other, which is exactly what will happen if they are not hitting the map at the same time. But it is possible that both run at the same time, perform the first `putIfAbsent` successfully, then fail at the second, because the second key is already registered. So both attempts are rejected.

Comment: @Holger Got it. Thank you. If startNewChallenge gets called at the same time for both same user in different order, both could fail. Do you have a blog where I could follow you?

Comment: @Tarun not yet. Perhaps, one day I’ll start one…

Answer (score 0):

You must review your code.

You cannot do this in one time as you have two names to check. 
Even in a conventional (iterating) way you would have in the best case two operation. 
So anyway you will need to do at least two access on the map.
I suggest you to use your actual map without the concatenation of strings, so yes, one Challenge will appear two time in the map, one for each participant. Then you will be able to check easily if a user is engaged.

If you need to know with whom he is engaged, simply store the both names in the Challenge class.

Of course lock your map when you are looking for both entries. A function who return a Boolean will do the job !

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective it's possible, but the map has to use individual player names as keys, so for both players we have to put one challenge twice.
Having this, we can introduce additional async checking whether the new challenge was successful stored for the both players.

```java
private boolean put(Map<String, Challenge> challenges, String firstPlayerName,
        String secondPlayerName,
        Challenge newChallenge) {

    if(firstPlayerName.compareTo(secondPlayerName) > 0) {
        String tmp = firstPlayerName;
        firstPlayerName = secondPlayerName;
        secondPlayerName = tmp;
    }

    boolean firstPlayerAccepted = newChallenge == challenges.merge(firstPlayerName, newChallenge,
            (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue.isInitiated() ? oldValue : newValue);
    boolean secondPlayerAccepted = firstPlayerAccepted
            && newChallenge == challenges.merge(secondPlayerName, newChallenge,
            (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue.isInitiated() ? oldValue : newValue);

    boolean success = firstPlayerAccepted && secondPlayerAccepted;
    newChallenge.initiate(success);
    if (firstPlayerAccepted) {
        // remove unsuccessful
        challenges.computeIfPresent(firstPlayerName, (s, challenge) -> challenge.isInitiated() ? challenge : null);
        if (secondPlayerAccepted) {
            challenges.computeIfPresent(secondPlayerName, (s, challenge) -> challenge.isInitiated() ? challenge : null);
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

```java
class Challenge {

    private final CompletableFuture<Boolean> initiated = new CompletableFuture<>();

    public void initiate(boolean success) {
        initiated.complete(success);
    }

    public boolean isInitiated() {
        try {
            return initiated.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    enter code here
...
}
```

Comment: What if `oldValue.isInitiated()` evaluates to `false` during `merge` but would evaluate to `true` one nanosecond later? Further, the `computeIfPresent` operations could remove an arbitrary challenge of a newer `put` attempt which didn’t reach the `newChallenge.initiate(success);` yet.

Comment: @Holger It's impossible, isInitiated always returns one value, `true` or `false` depending from `newChallenge.initiate(success);` line

Comment: Oh right, it’s a blocking call. Then, of course, two concurrent `put` calls can easily lead to a deadlock. Just imagine what happens if `put(map, "foo", "bar", …)` and `put(map, "bar", "foo", …)` run parallel.

Comment: @Holger  there must be always new challenge instances instead the ellipsis in your put invocations, as consequence there are no common shared resources to cause deadlock

Comment: Of course, I assume that the concurrent `put(map, "foo", "bar", …)` and `put(map, "bar", "foo", …)` use difference challenge objects. When both operations use the same map, one thread will do `challenges.merge("foo"…)` successfully, the other thread will do `challenges.merge("bar"…)` successfully. Then, in the next step, both threads will see each other’s challenge object in the second `merge` step, calling `oldValue.isInitiated()`, leading to a deadlock.

Comment: @Holger you are right, I've just realized it before your comment,
there's necessity to keep the keys in a particular order,
added it in the code